# How do I boost::range::sort() a boost::transformed_range?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-range

I want to get the unique elements from a `vector<foo>` based on a member of `foo`. I am using `boost::adaptors::transform` to select the member, then sorting, then using `boost::adaptors::unique`. I'm having trouble getting the sort step to work. Leaving aside the `unique` call for now, I've tried the below code on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b446828c9ffe2d0).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/sort.hpp>

struct foo
{
    foo(std::string a) : bar(a) {}

    std::string bar;
    bool operator<(const foo& rhs) const {return bar < rhs.bar;}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<foo> words = { foo("z"), foo("d"), foo("b"), foo("c") };

    #if 1
    {
        auto asString = boost::adaptors::transform(words, +[](const foo& x) {return x.bar;});
        auto sortedStrings = boost::range::sort(asString);
        for (const auto& el : sortedStrings)
            std::cout << el << std::endl;
    }
    #else
    {
        auto asString = boost::adaptors::transform(words, +[](const foo& x) {return x.bar;});
        std::sort(asString.begin().base(), asString.end().base());
        for (const auto& el : asString)
            std::cout << el << std::endl;
    }

    {
        auto sortedStrings = boost::range::sort(words);
        for (const auto& el : sortedStrings)
            std::cout << el.bar << std::endl;
    }
    #endif


    return 0;
}
```

The `#if` section doesn't work:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/ios:40,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of 'void std::iter_swap(_ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator2) [with _ForwardIterator1 = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)(const foo&), __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<foo*, std::vector<foo> >, boost::iterators::use_default, boost::iterators::use_default>; _ForwardIterator2 = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)(const foo&), __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<foo*, std::vector<foo> >, boost::iterators::use_default, boost::iterators::use_default>]':
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:84:20:   required from 'void std::__move_median_to_first(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Iterator, _Iterator, _Compare) [with _Iterator = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)(const foo&), __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<foo*, std::vector<foo> >, boost::iterators::use_default, boost::iterators::use_default>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1918:34:   required from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)(const foo&), __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<foo*, std::vector<foo> >, boost::iterators::use_default, boost::iterators::use_default>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1950:38:   required from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)(const foo&), __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<foo*, std::vector<foo> >, boost::iterators::use_default, boost::iterators::use_default>; _Size = long int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1965:25:   required from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)(const foo&), __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<foo*, std::vector<foo> >, boost::iterators::use_default, boost::iterators::use_default>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]'
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:4707:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)(const foo&), __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<foo*, std::vector<foo> >, boost::iterators::use_default, boost::iterators::use_default>]'
/usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm/sort.hpp:33:14:   required from 'RandomAccessRange& boost::range::sort(RandomAccessRange&) [with RandomAccessRange = boost::range_detail::transformed_range<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)(const foo&), std::vector<foo> >]'
main.cpp:27:57:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:148:11: error: no matching function for call to 'swap(boost::iterators::detail::iterator_facade_base<boost::iterators::transform_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)(const foo&), __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<foo*, std::vector<foo> >, boost::iterators::use_default, boost::iterators::use_default>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::iterators::random_access_traversal_tag, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, long int, false, false>::reference, boost::iterators::detail::iterator_facade_base<boost::iterators::transform_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)(const foo&), __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<foo*, std::vector<foo> >, boost::iterators::use_default, boost::iterators::use_default>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::iterators::random_access_traversal_tag, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, long int, false, false>::reference)'
       swap(*__a, *__b);
```

Whereas the `std::sort` with the base iterator type in the `#else` section does work. I don't understand why. In my real use case, I am also using `boost::adaptors::indirect` and `boost::adaptors::filter` (and I'd prefer to do the filtering before doing the sorting, or at least try to do so and see how it performs), so that's why I'm not simply sorting `words` with a lambda predicate before doing the transform.

Comment: `boost::swap(*asString.begin(), *asString.begin());` failed.

Comment: You can't. Sorting requires random access.

Comment: @sehe transform() documentation claims it returns the same range type as it takes in, so it should be random access, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you have a view of temporary strings that you cannot swap. you may fix you code with the following:

```
auto asString = boost::adaptors::transform(words, +[](foo& x) -> std::string& {return x.bar;});
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86275b8c4b939aec)

Note that with that, you sort the string directly, and not the class.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense that `const foo& x` can't return a non-const reference to `bar`. Is the explicit `std::string&` necessary? It will return by value by default? In my real use case I discovered the const issue for a different reason. My real use case is making `boost::adaptors::unique` work on a vector of iterators into a set<string>, and of course the strings in the set can't be swapped, so the `.base()` approach can't work. Now I take a copy of the iterators sort/unique on that.

Comment: @MattChambers: care that `sort` also requires random accessor iterators,  so cannot be used with `filter` or `unique` view.

Comment: This is spiffy, but highly unlikely to be what people need, IYAM: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31653bbd316a795b

Comment: I have to `sort` it before my `unique` will do its job; I found that out the hard way. :) But yeah, I misread the filter documentation before; it would return a Bidirectional Range when given a random access range. So I would do transform -> sort -> filter -> unique.

Comment: You tease me with your fancy generic lambdas. I'm using VS2013 for now. :P Which, infuriatingly, also does not support the + prefix in a sane way.