# boost::transform_iterator and std::iter_swap

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, c++17

I am trying to generalize a function I have which used to take two iterators to a vector of a specific data-structure, and re-arrange the elements in a certain way using `std::iter_swap` (like `std::sort` does).

Since this function only actually needs a subset of the data, and I will need to use it in other contexts in the future, I thought about removing the dependency on the data structure, and use `boost::transform_iterator` at the point of call to handle the transformation.

Unfortunately, it seems that `boost::transform_iterator` is not happy with this change. I can imagine why: `std::iter_swap` is usually implemented as `std::swap(*lhs, *rhs)`, and dereferencing the `transform_iterator` does not yield the original element to swap in the correct way.

I was wondering if there was a way to handle this case. I am open to use `boost::range` or the experimental `std::ranges` ts if it needed.

This question is probably similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727801/how-do-i-boostrangesort-a-boosttransformed-range), but even there the solution ends up modifying the subset of data the algorithm needs, rather than the outside structure.

Here is an MWE:

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
};

template <typename It>
void my_invert(It begin, It end) {
    while (begin < end) {
        std::iter_swap(begin++, --end);
    }
}

template <typename It>
void my_print(It begin, It end) {
    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
        std::cout << (*begin) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> x{7,6,5,4,3,2};

    my_invert(std::begin(x), std::end(x));
    my_print(std::begin(x), std::end(x));

    auto unwrap = +[](const A & a) { return a.x; };

    std::vector<A> y{{9,8}, {7,6}, {5,4}, {3,2}};

    auto begin = boost::make_transform_iterator(std::begin(y), unwrap);
    auto end = boost::make_transform_iterator(std::end(y), unwrap);

    //my_invert(begin, end); // Does not work.
    my_print(begin, end);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Accessing the underlying iterator

You could access the [`base()`](https://github.com/boostorg/iterator/blob/b2adecb951af025698618f19a3c838bd314966dc/include/boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp#L270) property of `transform_iterator` (inherited publicly from `iterator_adaptor`) to implement your custom `transform_iter_swap`, for swapping the underlying data of the wrapped iterator.

E.g.:

```
template<class IteratorAdaptor>
void transform_iter_swap(IteratorAdaptor a, IteratorAdaptor b)
{
   std::swap(*a.base(), *b.base());
}

template <typename It>
void my_invert(It begin, It end) {
    while (begin < end) {
        transform_iter_swap(begin++, --end);
    }
}
```

After which your example (omitting the `std::vector` part) runs as expected:

```
my_invert(begin, end); // OK
my_print(begin, end);  // 3 5 7 9
```

If you want a general function template to cover both the boost (adaptor) iterators as well as typical iterators, you could e.g. use `if constexpr` (C++17) based on whether the iterators public `typedef` `iterator_category` derives from `boost::iterators::no_traversal_tag` or not:

```
// expand includes with
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_categories.hpp>

template <class It>
void iter_swap(It a, It b) {
  if constexpr(std::is_base_of<
        boost::iterators::no_traversal_tag,
        typename It::iterator_category>::value) {
      std::swap(*a.base(), *b.base());
    }
  else {
    std::swap(*a, *b);
  }
}

template <typename It>
void my_invert(It begin, It end) {
    while (begin < end) {
        iter_swap(begin++, --end);
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, and I did think about this. The only problem I see is that basically forces me to use transform iterators in `my_invert` even if I don't need them (for example for the first vector). I could make it a separate implementation (something like `my_invert_transformed`), but it would be nice if there was a way to keep the method general.

Comment: You could leverage SFINAE to chose between "real iterators" and e.g. special ones (such as boosts `transform_iterator`): I could add an example.

Comment: Maybe I could use an `if constexpr` to automatically call `base()` if it exists, but it looks a bit like a hack.

Comment: Another idea I am looking into is to specialize `std::iter_swap` for the boost iterators so that they do the right thing..

Comment: @Svalorzen I think it would be better to leverage whether we are working with boosts iterator types or not, rather than existance of an arbitary method (`base()`). Regarding specializing `std::iter_swap`: I usually take very much case before chaninging, even by specialization, the behaviour of std lib constructs.

Comment: I know, I'm mostly just trying to evaluate all possible venues of approach so that I can actually choose the one that I like the most. I'm also trying to look into boost::range and the ranges ts since I'm not very familiar with them. Maybe the allow to do this kind of stuff?

Comment: @Svalorzen I haven't used `boost:range` myself, but maybe that's an option. I expanded my answer with one (C++17) approach for when to swap based on `base()` or not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the unary predicate you've passed. Notice, that since you allow the return type to be deduced, the return type is deduced to be an int, a copy is returned, and the compilation fails when you try to swap two unmodifiable ints. However, if you were to specify the return type to be int&, like so:

```
 auto unwrap = [](A & a)->int& { return a.x; }; // explicitly demand to return ref
```

It will compile, and reverse the elements. Tested on gcc 8.1.0 and clang 6.0.0.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed can be one of the problems. However notice that in your solution only `a.x` gets reverted. What I would like is that the original elements get reverted. As in, `{9, 8}` should be last, but not be changed to `{3,8}`.

Comment: Well, I doubt that you can get it to work, and honestly can't see a reason why you would want it to work- you can still reverse the elements using just the normal iterators of the vector, and e.g. only print with the transform_iterator.

Comment: The code I have posted is an example. I am not printing the data. I am doing complex transformations on them, and the swaps are conditional on the data I am feeding to the function. Thus no, I cannot reverse the element using the normal iterators.