# Apply projection prior to piping to view or action

Tags: c++, range-v3

I would like to apply a projection prior to piping a range into an action or view. Consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/map.hpp>
#include <range/v3/action/sort.hpp>
#include <range/v3/algorithm/for_each.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> strings{"1.2","100.2","11.2","0.2","2.2"};
    ranges::for_each(strings, [](const auto& str) { std::cout << str << std::endl; });
    
    strings | ranges::views::all | ranges::actions::sort;
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
    ranges::for_each(strings, [](const auto& str) { std::cout << str << std::endl; });

    return 0;
}
```

Say that I wish to convert the string to a double prior to sorting. Using the functional approach, this is possible:

```cpp
strings |= ranges::actions::sort(std::less{}, [](const auto& str) { return std::stod(str); });
```

However I'm wondering if there is a pipeline format which allows this instead, which applies this projection for all following operations, for example:

```cpp
strings | ranges::views::projection([](const auto&str ) { return std::stod(str); }) | ranges::actions::sort;
```

Note that using `ranges::views::transform` doesn't work as it creates a new range instead of a projection.

I'm also not sure if there's a caveat for using `strings | ranges::views::all | ranges::actions::sort` instead of `strings |= ranges::actions::sort` which is recommended in the range-v3 documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't a range be sorted in range-v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60338142/why-cant-a-range-be-sorted-in-range-v3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update(2021.01.26):

Doing actions on projected views might cause confusion. E.g. imagine a projection function with signature `int&(std::pair<int, int>&) / int&&(std::pair<int, int>&&)` that return the first component of a pair, apply that projection on a range of `std::pair<int, int>`. What should happen if we `filter`?

- It should return a range of `int` because we passed it a range of `int`.
- It should also return a range of `std::pair<int, int>` because we really want to filter the underlying range of `std::pair<int, int>`.

But it does not know we want which.

So it seems that it is not appropriate to treat projection as a standalone operation on range this time, instead it is more **clear** if the projection operation is an optional parameter of filter or sort.

---

Old answer(2021.01.15):

It is inefficient to implement sorting with projection and perhaps that's why it's not provided. You have to store the result of projection explicitly:
c++ - Why can't a range be sorted in range-v3? - Stack Overflow
[Why can't a range be sorted in range-v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60338142/why-cant-a-range-be-sorted-in-range-v3)

The standard version says the complexity of projection is (N·log(N)) (so it may be faster to project the elements and store them before sorting):
std::ranges::sort - cppreference.com
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort

Comment: I guess I'm not concerned about the sort operation in particular so maybe it's a poor example. It could instead be a views::filter or other operations - the point is that I would like all following operations to consider a projection instead of having to provide the same projection to every following operation.

Comment: @singhh23  Doing actions on projected views might cause confusion. E.g. imagine a projection function with signature `int&(std::pair<int, int>&) / int&&(std::pair<int, int>&&)` that return the first component of a pair, apply that projection on a range of `std::pair<int, int>`. What should happen if we `filter`? It should return a range of `int` because we passed it a range of `int`, it should also return a range of `std::pair<int, int>` because we really want to filter the underlying range of `std::pair<int, int>`, but it does not know we want which.

Comment: @singhh23  So it seems that it is not appropriate to treat projection as a standalone operation on range this time, instead it is more **clear** if the projection operation is an optional parameter of `filter` or `sort`.

Comment: a similar one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727801/how-do-i-boostrangesort-a-boosttransformed-range

Comment: Yea, your comment on return type makes sense to me - could you update your answer with it and I'll accept?

Comment: @singhh23  Okay, the comments are added to the answer.